# Get html code of table row with jquery

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm using mustachesjs to add HTML code to my pages. I tried to add a row in a table using mustachejs but the td element or tr element are not in the html code.

Here is the mustachejs template :

```
<div id="tpl-general-tr-phone">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{{ number }}</td>
    <td>{{ type }}</td>
    <td>{{ published }}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript code :

```
$.get( "mustache", function(template) {

        var output = Mustache.render($(template).filter('#tpl-general-tr-phone').html(),
            {
                number : phonenumber,
                type : phonetype,
                published : 1
            });

        console.log(output);

        $('.table-phones').append(output);

    });
```

Anyone knows the solution to this problem ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why is the tr element inside a div rather than a table?

Comment: @nnnnnn The div is used to defined the mustache template to get. I have multiple templates in the same file, the div is used to get the template that i want to use. Here, the template is used to add a row to a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the tr element are not well interpreted if they are not in a table element. What I did is to change my template like this :

```
<div id="tpl-general-tr-phone">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>{{ number }}</td>
            <td>{{ type }}</td>
            <td>{{ published }}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table></div>
```

And I get the template in javascript like this :

```
var output = Mustache.render($(template).filter('#tpl-general-tr-phone').find("tbody").html(), ...
```

This solution works fine